# App is rejected from Google Play store due to Policy Issue. There is no option for deactivate non-compliant APK

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Firstly My App is remove from Google Play store because of Policy issue like Flurry SDK version Update. So after that i have remove this SDK from my App code and Build APK and Add on Production mode to release. So Google Play store rejected my app. and They given same policy Reason.

So i have check email that send by Google play store for detailing. So They review my old APK. Like My Apk **version is 34** and using flurry sdk.They remove because of policy issue. then i have submitted new build with **version 35** and Removing flurry sdk. Still they review my old apk and Given reason your app using this SDK and version is 34.

**Also i did appeal for this and they give me solution like below**

Before resubmitting your app for further review, please make sure to DEACTIVATE the non compliant APK (APK Version: 34, Track: Production) and increment the version number of APK. Please note that our policy applies to every content in your app including all release types (e.g. Production, Internal test, Closed, Open). You may choose to deactivate unused APKs.

Step 2: Submit an update with the increased version number to your app

1. Go to your Play Console.
2. Select the app.
3. Go to App bundle explorer.
4. Select the non-compliant APK/app bundle's App version at the top right dropdown menu, and make a note of which releases they are under.
5. Go to the track with the policy issue. It will be one of these 4 pages: Internal / Closed / Open testing or Production.
6. Near the top right of the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage track first)
   If the release with the violating APK is in a draft state, discard the release.
7. Add the policy compliant version of app bundles or APKs.
   The non-compliant version of app bundles or APKs is under the "Not included" section of this release. For further guidance, please see the "Not included (app bundles and APKs)" section in this Play Console Help article.
   The new release is rolled out 100% and completely deactivates the non-compliant APK.
8. To save any changes you make to your release, select Save.
9. When you've finished preparing your release, select Review release.

**=======================================================================**

So there is no option for "Select the non-compliant APK/app bundle's App version at the top right dropdown menu, and make a note of which releases they are under."

As we know Google play store ui update they remove delete option from App bundle explorer.

Also i contact support community and emails also they give same answer as Above.

So how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @arti have you got solution for this issue? me also having same issue

Answer (score 0):

There is something that Play store employees don't (always) say or it's not clear in their emails. You have to update all channels (internal test, closed beta etc), not only the production channel, if on those channels there is a version of the app that is affected by a policy issue. It's not important if on a beta channel there is an older version from the one that is published in the production channel.

What you have to do is publish the app on the "lowest" channel (i.e. internal testing) and promote it to the next "upper" channel (i.e. closed beta) and repeat until to have the same version promoted to the production channel.

You can also create empty releases in all affected channels that are not the production channel and only upload the fixed version to the production channel.

You can create an empty <s>version</s> release in the same way you create a normal <s>version</s> release but without upload an apk/aab. Remember that in this case you have to give to the release a name since the field will not have the default name of the apk (since you don't upload any).

Comment: i have try to internal testing without APK/App bundle file. But getting error like require  apk/abb file.

Comment: In my experience you can create an empty release - a release without uploading an apk/aab.

Answer (score 0):

ok I had similar issue and solved it.

The line in the email they send out says:

*"Click Manage track > Create new release"*

should be rewritten as

*"Click Manage track" then INSIDE the track click the button called Create new release".*

I thought 'Create new release' was a general instruction so I was creating new CLOSED TRACK for each new release.

And later the non conforming aab was in an old CLOSED track.

You need to go into App Bundle Explorer and see which track is using the aab/apk

then in EACH TRACK Prod, Open, Closed, Internal open the track and press "Create new release" and upload the latest aab.

The old aab should now be in the NOT INCLUDED section.

**When an app bundle is removed from ALL TRACKS... ONLY then it will appear as InActive in the App Bundle Explorer.**

The hideously FLAT and WHITE all over UI of Google Play Console DOES NOT HELP as it jumps all over the place!!